# CS50 Filter(more) Edges Problem. Why can I not accurately calculate edge pixels?

Tags: css, image, cs50, bmp

Hi I am confused as to what is wrong with my code related to the "edges" filter portion of the problem.
I am able to apply a filter that detects edges. For some reason I fail the check50. I am only able to apply the filter to middle pixels. Any guidance would be much appreciated. I am wondering if I am approaching this problem the incorrect way.

With this code I am just ignoring the calculations for the "black pixels" or the pixels outside of the range of height/width.

Here is my code:

````
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //create temporary array
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    //initialize sobel arrays
    int gxarray[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gyarray[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    //loop through each ith pixel in jth column
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j ++)
        {
                float gx_red = 0;
                float gx_blue = 0;
                float gx_green = 0;
                float gy_red = 0;
                float gy_blue = 0;
                float gy_green = 0;

            //use the temporary array grid to calculate each gx value
            //check if it is a corner or side pixel - and treat that pixel as black pixel
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k ++)
            {

                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l ++)
                {
                    //calculate the gx and gy for each color by multiply each of
                    //check if they are corner or sidepixels
                    if (i + k < 0 || i + k >= height)
                    {
                        continue;

                    }
                    if (j + l < 0 || j + l >= width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //otherwise calculate each color value

                    gx_red += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gx_blue += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gx_green += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];

                    gy_red += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gy_blue += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gy_green += temp[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];

                }

            }

            //times each number by itself then, add them, then square root them
            int red = 0 + round(sqrt(gx_red * gx_red + gy_red * gy_red));
            int blue = 0 + round(sqrt(gx_blue * gx_blue + gy_blue * gy_blue));
            int green = 0 + round(sqrt(gx_green * gx_green + gy_green * gy_green));

            image[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;



            //cap it by 255
            if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;
            }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
            {
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;
            }

        }
    }

    return;
}


```[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bExI.png
````

Comment: This is one of the corresponding errors that I get:

Comment: Figured out the issue. I had capped the summed Gx and Gy color channels and didn't cap the values at 255 before making the change on the actual image pixel. I was unintentionally truncating color channel values.

Answer (score 1):

at the beginning of the code you create a temporary image to store all the rgb values called temp[height][width]. However, you do not apply the rgb values to tmp. You'll have to first assign the values to tmp and at the end of the code assign it to the original image. And also get the values from the original image instead of the temp. This should work:

````
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //create temporary array
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            temp[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    //initialize sobel arrays
    int gxarray[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int gyarray[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    //loop through each ith pixel in jth column
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j ++)
        {
                float gx_red = 0;
                float gx_blue = 0;
                float gx_green = 0;
                float gy_red = 0;
                float gy_blue = 0;
                float gy_green = 0;

            //use the temporary array grid to calculate each gx value
            //check if it is a corner or side pixel - and treat that pixel as black pixel
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k ++)
            {

                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l ++)
                {
                    //calculate the gx and gy for each color by multiply each of
                    //check if they are corner or sidepixels
                    if (i + k < 0 || i + k >= height)
                    {
                        continue;

                    }
                    if (j + l < 0 || j + l >= width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //otherwise calculate each color value

                    gx_red += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gx_blue += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gx_green += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen * gxarray[k + 1][l + 1];

                    gy_red += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtRed * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gy_blue += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtBlue * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];
                    gy_green += image[i + k][j + l].rgbtGreen * gyarray[k + 1][l + 1];

                }

            }

            //times each number by itself then, add them, then square root them
            int red = round(sqrt(gx_red * gx_red + gy_red * gy_red));
            int blue = round(sqrt(gx_blue * gx_blue + gy_blue * gy_blue));
            int green = round(sqrt(gx_green * gx_green + gy_green * gy_green));

            //cap it by 255
            if (red > 255)
            {
                red = 255;
            }

            if (blue > 255)
            {
                blue = 255;
            }

            if (green > 255)
            {
                green = 255;
            }


            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = red;
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = green;


        }
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < height; m++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < width; n++)
        {
            image[m][n] = temp[m][n];
        }
    }

    return;
}


```[enter image description here][1]
````